# How to trim the column in DB2

Tags: db2

How to trim the column in DB2 for the below given input

`00652835065718`
`00052835065718`

I need to use SQL to remove all leading zeros from the values so that the final output will be:

652835065718
52835065718

The Column is VARCHAR

I have tried the below query

```
select TRIM(L '0' FROM ID) from ITM where ID = '0652835065718'
```

but it's not working in my DB2 version `9.1.5`

Comment: "Not working" how?  At the moment, this is only a `SELECT` statement, so the values in the db are still the same.  Your query also appears to have a typo - you only have one leading `'0'` (as opposed to two in your sample data).

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your DB2 Platform

If you're on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, then the answer is similar to what @Teun Loonen said, I'm guessing that it's the backticks that are messing things up. The correct syntax for the [`TRIM`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023198.html) function on DB2 is:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ID)
FROM ITM
```

If you're on Mainframe DB2, then you can use the [`LTRIM`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_ltrim.htm) scalar function:

```
SELECT LTRIM(ID, '0')
FROM ITM
```

Comment: Thanks for specifically breaking out answers for both flavors of DB2!

Answer (score 1):

DB2 will automatically remove leading 0s from Integers so just use CAST, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS INTEGER)
```

Here is a test.

```
SELECT CAST('0012345' AS INTEGER) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

1          
-----------
  12345
```

Comment: is it possible to use cast in where condition like `CAST(ID AS INTEGER)=12345` . i have tried this but it's not working.

Comment: You can use CAST in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -1):

by simply using the trim function

```
select TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM `field` ) as field FROM table
```

edit: *removed link*

Comment: i have tried this, but my db2 version is not supporting this query

Comment: The link is for MySQL not DB2.

Comment: Can u use the cast function to numeric or is it possible that the column contains more than [0-9] numbers.