# DB2 leading zeroes

Tags: sql, database, db2, zos

How to trim only zeroes in a leading position in a string?

I'm writing a DB2 script that removes all leading zeroes from a string that could be only 13 characters long.
What I wrote so far:

> ltrim(replace(Field, '00000',''))

That works as follows:

```
0000012345678111 -> 12345678111
0000012300000174 -> 123174
```

Now, I need to delete ONLY the five leading zeroes, not the zeroes in the middle and I already tried to convert to decimal, but if I have, for example, only two zeroes leading, I want to leave them in the same position.

For example (converting to decimal) :

```
001234566890000 -> 1234566890000
```

I want no Changes in the left string.

How could I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trim the column in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241738/how-to-trim-the-column-in-db2)

Comment: Hi Henrik. Unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: what does not work? Please comment in the linked question

Comment: Solved in My answer just wroted

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 6 leading zeroes? Should one be kept, none, or all six?

Comment: One zero, i have to delete only the five leading zeroes

Comment: what if there are two leading zeroes? or three? or four?

Comment: With 2,3,4 leading zeros i want to leave them as it is

Comment: It seems that your requirements are not clear then. Please edit the question to show more valid examples. The second code block says the number on the left should not change, but it is longer than 13 character so it has to change. Is the number on the right correct? or should it have 2 leading zeroes and 2 trailing zeroes 0012345668900. this is all very inconsistent. No one will be able to help you until you have coherent requirements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the Solution by myself.
I've used nested function:

`substr( replace( ltrim( replace(Field,'00000', '     ')), ' ', '0'), 1, 13)` 
(please, i can't indent properly from My smartphone, could someone do it for me? Thanks)

This solve My question

Comment: This looks overly complicated. Why not just LTRIM?

Comment: Because ltrim works only with spaces. Without this 'trick', i had even the middle zeroes deleted and then something like this: 0012340078900 - 1234789 At the end

Comment: Not true! LTRIM accepts a second parameter to tell which characters to trim. So `ltrim(field, ' 0')` would trim both blanks and zeroes.

Comment: But if the string has a 0 in first position, this could not work, right? Am i wrong?

Comment: Also, the above will only work for the one specific case where you tested it.

Comment: You are wrong. Just try it. The second parameter of ltrim tells which characters to trim, the order of the characters in the second parameter do not matter, they are trimmed individually, no matter what order they appear in the string. the result of `ltrim('0 01203', ' 0')` will be '1203'.

Comment: Your answer does not work because i want to have the same string lenght. For example if My input string 0123045678 has 10 chars, the ltrim function works ok with the zeroes, but My output string becomes 123045678 that has 9 chars

Comment: First, where is that in your question?

Comment: Are you just trying to make a long string all the same length by keeping the right side of the string? Then you would want something like `right(trim(field),13)`. If you really want 13 characters padded on the left with zeroes, you could try `right('00000' || trim(field), 13)`. But we are all just guessing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use LTRIM to get rid of the zeroes. If you want a resulting string length, make it a string of that type again. To have CHAR(13) as result:

```
CHAR(LTRIM(inputvalue, '0'), 13)
```